# Linq Query - Selective Fields as DataTable?

Tags: c#

I want to create a datatable from linq query. 
The below code selects all filed, but i need select few fileds like "door_no","street_name","city_name","post_code","date of birth" and need to create it as Datatable.

```
var Results = from SelRow in MyDtb1.AsEnumerable() where SelRow.Field("door_no") != null select SelRow;
DataTable ChkResult = Results.CopyToDataTable();
```

Any Better Ideas

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an anonymous type like this:

```
var Results = from SelRow in MyDtb1.AsEnumerable()
              where !SelRow.IsNull("door_no")
              select new
              {
                  DoorNumber = SelRow["door_no"],
                  CityName = SelRow["city_name"],
                  ZipCode = SelRow["post_code"]
              };
```